# Practical purpose of the null-coalescing assignment operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, null

#### Nulls in C#

One of the new C# features allows us to *get rid of nulls in our code* with *nullable reference types*. We are encouraged to add

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

to the project file due to problems like [described here](https://dev.to/mbernard/why-null-in-c-is-so-bad-cid).

Of course, a lot of existing projects don't want to add this. Many, many errors need to be solved when enabling this functionality, so a lot of  **legacy nulls** will still be around. But do we really need additional null-functionality in the language?

#### The confusion

In the same C# 8.0 release, the null-coalescing assignment operator (`??=`) has been introduced (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment)). I understand the behavior, but which problem(s) does it solve for us? Why would we want to assign `b` to `x` when it's null `x ??= b` and have e.g. `x = a` when it's not null?

The examples I found are very theoretical, can someone give me a **real-world application of this operator**? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A real world example would be lazy loading a backing field on first access when that backing field is null. Something like this:

```
private string _dbQuery;
private string DbQuery => _dbQuery ??= GetQuery(queryName);
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest use case is that depending on C# version we previously would have done:

```
if (number == null)
{
    number = someVale;
}
```

or

```
number = number ?? someValue;
```

With the new assignment operator we can shorten it further to:

```
number ??= someNumber;
```

A real world example though:

```
public void WriteErrorToLog(string errorMessage, Exception ex)
{
    Log.Warn(errorMessage ??= AppConstants.UnhandledError, ex);
}
```

Not a perfect real world example. But lets say I want to log soft errors. Writing a template message, with an exception would be much preferable to generating a second error/ exception.

Comment: An assignment to errorMessage here is unnecessary. It would be even better to have errorMessage const. You can write the same with less bytes if you use ?? instead of ??=. You just want one or the other. You needn't assign one into the other. Perhaps if there was a lot of stuff that needed to be done in the function scope over it, ok.

Answer (score 0):

The null-coalescing operator **??** returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result. The **??** operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

Available in C# 8.0 and later, the null-coalescing assignment operator **??=** assigns the value of its right-hand operand to its left-hand operand only if the left-hand operand evaluates to null. The **??=** operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

```
List<int> numbers = null;
int? a = null;

(numbers ??= new List<int>()).Add(5);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));  // output: 5

numbers.Add(a ??= 0);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));  // output: 5 0
Console.WriteLine(a);  // output: 0
```

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator#operator-overloadability)

Comment: Vote up for explaining about "??". I am interested to know what similar capabilities are available in other languages.